# fullcalendar changing to 24 hour format js

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar.io v2.4 in my project.
and I'm tried to figure out how to change the date format.
I looked in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat and I understood that I need to change the 'slotLabelFormat' to be :

```
slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm"
```

but where is "slotLabelFormat" should be? 
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this ...

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10),
        navLinks: true, 
        slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, 
        events: 'feed.php'
    });
```